# Symfony Image Upload Validator Not Working

Tags: validation, symfony, silex

I've got a Silex application with a file upload form that includes an Image validator.  The other field validators appear to be working (i.e. I can cause the form submit to invalidate), but the file upload never appears to be validated.  I've tried validating the upload with both `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\File` and `Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Image` but have had no luck--everything comes through as valid.  Even the following example, where the constraints can never be satisfied, doesn't reject the upload.  What am I missing here?

```
$this->validation = new Assert\Collection(array(
    'first_name' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
    'last_name' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
    'email' => new Assert\Email(),
    'address_1' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
    'city' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
    'state' => new Assert\Regex('/^(' . join('|', array_keys($this->state_list)) . ')$/'),
    'zip' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
    'photo' => new Assert\Image(array(
            'maxWidth' => 400,
            'minWidth' => 1000
    )),
    'caption' => new Assert\NotBlank()
));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some hours debugging the Symfony Validate files, I found out that the problem is that the files are not in `$request->request` but rather in `$request->files` so the solution is to copy/move it so validator can validate it.

```
 $request->request->set("photo", $request->files->get('photo'));
```